# selectOutput5, Linkted to Radio Button

Tags: anylogic

My question is how can I link 'Radio Button' with 'Select Output 5'. The idea is to select output of the agents based on corresponding radio button. [Click to Image of the simple problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfjqd.png)

Thank you so much in advance.

Best Regards,
JB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the radio button has a getValue() method so you can use that on your selectOutput using conditions

```
radio.getValue()==0

radio.getValue()==1
```

etc...